# RestEasy-post-method with abstract param

Tags: json, parameters, interface, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a resteasy webservice running on wildfly 8. A post method consumes content type json. With normal object as parameter its working fine. But if the parameter is an interface I get

> problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

How can I tell resteasy to map the interface type to a specific implementation?

Here the implementation of the webservice method:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response signUpJson(ObjInterface obj) {
    Response.ResponseBuilder builder;
    // do something
    builder = Response.ok();
    return builder.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create and register a `MessageBodyReader`, more here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html